# Create and call a function inside a class method

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I am trying to call a function inside a function but it is not getting called and no error is coming up.

I created a `$addFile` function to reuse it in the switch statement below.

```
public function findFilesBySize($path, $size)
{
    if((!is_array($size)) || (count($size) != 2))
        throw new \Exception("Second parameter should be array of comparison operator and value", 1);


    $path = (is_dir($path)) ? $path : getcwd();
    $files = array();
    $addFiles = function(array $files, \DirectoryIterator $file ) 
                {
                    die('working'); // function not getting called
                    $files[] = $file->getFileName();
                };
    $iterator = new \DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        if($file->isDir())
            continue;
        switch ($size[0]) {
            case '<':
                if($file->getSize() < $size[1]) {
                    $addFiles($files, $file);
                }
                break;   
            case '>':
                if($file->getSize() > $size[1]) {
                    $addFiles($files, $file);
                }
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

**Additional/Optional Part:**
I don't like the switch approach and if somebody can suggest any good approach to do the `if($file->getSize() $operator $value)` then please let me know.

Comment: Function worked for me (php < 5.3 maybe?), but `$files` array you build lives within that function scope only (for one call) - pass it by reference: `$addFiles = function(array &$files, ...`. My first thought approach would be some FileList class extending DirectoryIterator with two methods in it: `getSmaller($size)`, `getBigger($size)` or sth like that.

Comment: Yes i passed it by reference working fine but the function is not getting called this way install i did `addFiles()`. I even tried with `call_user_func`. Anyways can you post the answer so that i can close this question.